# Is the Open Graph prefix attribute necessary in HTML 5?

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph, prefix

I've read conflicting information about whether the prefix attribute is needed in HTML 5.

For example, is this code correct for Open Graph data in the head? Would it be okay to remove the prefix attribute?

```
<head prefix="og: https://ogp.me/ns# article: https://ogp.me/ns/article# fb: https://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="example">
    <meta property="og:title" content="example">
    <meta property="og:description" name="description" content="example">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com">
    <meta property="og:type" content="article">
    <meta property="article:author" content="https://example.com/profile">
    <meta property="article:section" content="Products">
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="123">
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what consumers of the mark-up do. Since `og:` is named as a predefined prefix in the [RDFa 1.1 Core Initial Context](https://www.w3.org/2011/rdfa-context/rdfa-1.1.html), any RDFa 1.1 compliant consumer will work fine if you omit the `og:` prefix.

Similarly, even if the consumer isn't RDFa 1.1 compliant, but "knows" the prefix anyway, you can omit it.

On the other hand, neither `article:` nor `fb:`are defined in the Core Initial Context, so you're relying that much more on the consumer just "knowing" (or "guessing") that prefix.

None of this is really HTML5 related. RDFa is not an explicit part of HTML5 in the way microdata is, but can be regarded as an "add-on" or [applicable specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#other-applicable-specifications) in HTML5 terminology

So, in general, it could be regarded as safer to include the populated prefix attribute. If, however, you know all the consumers you're targeting will interpret the prefixes correctly anyway, then you would be free to omit the attribute.